# Spring load properties from database using Factory Bean of Properties

Tags: java, spring

My current code has properties being loaded from a file. I need to move the properties to a database table and configure the property place holder configurer to load them from database.

Below is the Current code which is loading properties from file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig  {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

There is a factoryBean of Properties defined which will load the properties from database table and I would like to hook it up to the existing ProprtyPlaceHolderConfigurer. I had changed my current code as below:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig  {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer =  new     
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
       configurer.setProperties(propertiesLoader.getObject());
    return configurer;
}


}
```

propertiesLoader.getObject() is the factory bean that loada the data from database. But I get  "Could not resolve placeholder values" exception on application startup. How can I construct a bean of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer using the properties loaded by the factory bean.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting the Properties in `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and not in `Configurer` and returning the same?

Comment: Sorry that was  a typo error. I had edited the code